# C++ design pattern: Possible to have inherited method private to derived class?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, inheritance

Is the following setup / design pattern possible in C++?

- a Leader class
- a Worker class

  - has method M()
- a MyWorker class (inherits Worker)

The Leader class has many Workers and needs to call method M() from the Worker class. However, I don't want any implementation of Worker (i.e. MyWorker) to have access to method M(). Neither public, private, nor protected seem to work in this case.

Is this setup possible? Or how should I design things otherwise?

Thanks

Edit: (adding example case)

Suppose M() is GiveMoney(), Leader = Parent, and Worker = Child. I only want the Parent to be able to give the Child money (and Children can't give themselves money).

Comment: You want a class to not have access to its own method, but for the method to be callable from another class?  I don't think this is possible in any language.

Comment: Post code, if defining M() as private; and doing an extension via public should cause the MyWorker to NOT have access to the private method.  The fact that M() is private should work just fine as long as the Worker (the original owner of M()) is the only thing calling M() since normally an instance can operate on private method/members on other instances of the same class.

Comment: If `M()` is defined as **private** and `Leader` is a friend of `Worker`, everything should work as you wish - if I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could either:

1. Make `M()` a private function in `Worker`, and declare `Leader` to be a friend of `Worker`.
2. Move the logic for `M()` out of `Worker` and into `Leader`.  Personally, this is the approach I would take, given that whatever `M()` does, you dont want any other `Worker` to do.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Leader
{
  private:
    virtual char M() = 0;
  public:
    void foo() { std::cout << M(); }
};

class Worker : public Leader
{
  private:
    virtual char M() { return 'm'; }
};
```

Then

```
int main()
{
  Worker w;
  w.foo();
}
```

prints `m` and

```
class MyWorker : public Worker
{
  void foo2() { std::cout << M(); }
};
```

results in a compilation error, complaining that

> ‘virtual char Worker::M()’ is private.

Comment: What if I don't want the Worker to inherit the Leader? An example, suppose the method is AddFood() and I don't want workers to be able to feed themselves.

Comment: Then you have to make `Worker` a friend of `Leader` or you have to rewrite `Leader` in such a way that it does not have to call `Worker::M` (e.g. by moving the functionality that requires the call into the `Worker` class (but that might not be appropriate in your particular situation)).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? What are you actually trying to achieve? Knowing your end-goal would help us help you find the answer you're looking for.

If your want to hide some implementation details completely, your best bet is to make a seperate base-class for the public side of the workers have your private workers include the public bits by composition.

**Edit** Sounds to me like you're making life unnecessarily difficult for yourself. Unless someone else has control over the child worker implementation, why not just avoid calling give money from the child workers?

Something like this might work for your example:

```
class Parent // Leader
{
private:
    Child* m_pChildren;
};

class Child : public ChildSelf
{
public:
    char GiveMoney() { return 'm'; }
};

class ChildSelf
{
    Run();
    Jump();
    ClimbTrees();
};

class MyChild : public ChildSelf
{
    void RunFaster() { Run(); Run(); }
};
```

Your child worker implementations only have access to ChildSelf which gives you the level of safety you're looking for.. ?

Answer (score 0):

Have `M` private, and declare `Leader` as a friend of `Worker`. You can still implement `M` in derived classes of `Worker`:

```
class Leader;

class Worker
{
    virtual void M() = 0;
    friend class Leader;
};

class Leader
{
    Worker* w;

public:
    void doSomething() { w->M(); }
};

class MyWorker : public Worker
{
    void M() { ... } // No problem. Even if `M` is private in the base class, it
                     // can still be overridden, but not accessed.
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you should look into the Visitor design pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

It's not exactly the same approach, but I believe if you define a `Visit(Worker)` method on the `Leader` class and an `Accept(Leader)` method on the `Worker` class that then calls `private M()`, you can get the functionality you're looking for.

Seeing as my post was downvoted I decided it might help if I give a little extra information:

```
class Leader;

class Worker
{
virtual void M() = 0;
public:
    void Accept( const Leader & w)
        {
            M();
        }
};

class Leader
{
public:
void Visit ( Worker & w) const
    {
    w.Accept(*this);
    }
};

class MyWorker : public Worker
{
virtual void M()
    {
    std::cout << "M()" << std::endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
Leader l;
MyWorker myW;
myW.Accept(l)
return 0;
}
```

The only way to have `M()` called is via the use of a `Leader`, `Worker` is an abstract class, and can't even be instantiated, though you can provide a default behaviour for `M()` if you wish.